# Hacks to access iOS APIs through Flex?

Tags: iphone, flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I am building a Flex iPhone application that in an ideal world would need to open up the iPhone SMS interface to send texts, make calls, access phone information (such as phone number) and access contact lists... I realise there isn't much in the way of accessing phone specific API's through flex at the moment, does anyone know if or when this is coming?

**My main question:** I seen this interesting article on [extending AIR to access android APIs](http://www.jamesward.com/2011/05/11/extending-air-for-android/) and was wondering if there was anything similar for accessing iOS APIs? What are people doing at the moment if you need to access iOS APIs? Is everyone waiting for an update to Flex/AIR?

I'd prefer to not splash out on a Mac!

Thanks
Phil

Comment: Flex is a mostly UI framework. So what's the deal with UI and iOS APIs?

Comment: Maybe I have worded it wrongly... sometimes I get AIR and Flex muddled up. I just want to create a Flex Mobile application that has access to iphone specific stuff such as contact books etc. But it appears there is no way to do this

Comment: call it *AS3* or just *Flash* next time, can also mention *AIR* if it about extra stuff that AIR provides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a URL Syntax from a Flex App to open the 'native' controls for sending / receiving text messages.  You can do somthing like this:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("sms:6175551212"))
```

It's not perfect, and still does not give you access to the address book, though.  To add message text, you can use the body attribute as a URL variable:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("sms:6175551212?body=hello%20there"))
```

([Source for body url variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme))

> I realise there isn't much in the way of accessing phone specific
>   API's through flex at the moment, does anyone know if or when this is
>   coming?

AIR 2.5 for TV has something called [ActionScript extensions](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/devices/pdfs/DevelopingActionScriptExtensionsForAdobeAIR.pdf), which allows you to write native code that can then be used from Adobe AIR.

[This Blog Post](http://www.flashmobileblog.com/2011/07/12/200k-adobe-air-app-challenge-for-sony-tablets/) mentions "the Sony Tablet S2 you will use the upcoming Native Extension feature in AIR 3".

So, I perceive that Air 3 will support the same ActionScript Extensions on a wider range of devices.

I believe most people who have immediate / important access to AIR APIs are building Native Apps and not using Adobe AIR.

---

My update 1/18/2011; AIR 3 has been released and it does indeed support [Native Extensions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) on iOS, Android, OSX, and Windows PCs.

Comment: "navigateToURL(new URLRequest("sms:6175551212"))". So how would this work exactly, I create the UI for "To:" and "Message:" and I make a URLRequest to "sms:phonenumbertosendto" to send an SMS? Thanks for the response

Comment: Its ok, found the page, cheers http://remotesynthesis.com/post.cfm/sending-text-messages-with-body-text-using-air-for-android-hackish-workaround

Comment: @Phil That's pretty much how it works; I made one update to my answer for how to include a message in the SMS.  I believe using the URL opens up the phones native SMS handler and prepopluates the phone number and message body.  You aren't actually sending the SMS from the app; you are just launching the devices native handler for the SMS protocol.  Similar to linking to a word doc or PDF from a web page.  It sends it on to the browser and the browser handles it.

Comment: Weird; I thought I linked to that page in my original answer..  sorry I must have missed it.

Comment: No worries, do you know if there is anything similar to make calls this way?

Comment: @Phil There is; I believe if you use 'tel' instead of 'SMS' it will initiate a phone call.